# Heroku expose localhost expo app to the web

Tags: heroku, expo

This might be a bit of a strange one, but essentially what I am trying to do is get a very basic testing environment for an early phase react native app using expo. I have been able to set up deployment for Android, however there are a lot of hurdles when it comes to IOS. So what I would like to do in the interim is use Heroku to expose the app which is started by `expo start` to the web. Where anyone can simply scan the qr code and access a testing version of the app painlessly.

At this stage, performance is not an issue and is only going to be viewed in a small team, so it seems that exactly what is given to me by `expo start` is perfect. I essentially want exactly what I would get by exposing it via ngrok except hosted on heroku.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: when attempting to use `expo start` as my web process, I get the following error when accessing it.

```
2022-03-21T07:07:01.116148+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=my-app.herokuapp.com request_id=a2ecgaa6-c314-4bec-c04c-42f5fe78333a fwd="102.65." dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

When specifying port 8080 or using the $PORT env var in my Procfile I receive the following error

```
2022-03-21T09:44:33.178619+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2022-03-21T09:44:33.220572+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2022-03-21T09:44:33.250176+00:00 app[web.1]: Error waiting for process to terminate: No child processes
2022-03-21T09:44:33.377609+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 22
2022-03-21T09:44:33.440277+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

My ProcFile looks as follows:

```
web: npm install -g expo-cli && expo start --port $PORT
```

Comment: Okay. So... what's the problem? Why can't you just run `expo start` as your web process?

Comment: @Chris I have now edited my question with the error I get when attempting this.

Comment: You'll need to bind to the port given by `PORT`. Trying another port like 8080 won't work. Please show your `Procfile` where you try to use the `PORT` environment variable.

Comment: I have just updated my answer with the contents of my Procfile. Thanks

Comment: That file must be named `Procfile` _exactly_, but your edit calls it `ProcFile`. What is it actually called? And where is it located?

Comment: It is located in the root folder, and it is called `Procfile` I can confirm that Heroku is in picking up the Procfile correctly.

Comment: Why are you doing `npm install` as part of your `web` process? That can easily take more than a minute. All dependencies should be declared in your `package.json` so they get installed at _build_ time, not runtime.

Comment: That is just for the expo cli, as Heroku prunes dev dependencies by default at run time. I can look at a better solution once I know that this is going to work.

Comment: There's a good chance that's the issue. You can prevent Heroku from pruning dev dependencies, which is actually probably what you want since you're running the dev server. Nothing should _ever_ be installed as part of your `web` process definition. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states, your application must bind to the web port *within 60 seconds of launch*. Installing packages as part of your `web` process definition can easily exhaust that time limit.

I suggest you

- make sure to include `expo-sli` in your `devDependencies`,
- [tell Heroku not to prune development dependencies](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#skip-pruning) by setting `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION` and / or `YARN_PRODUCTION` to `false`,
- modify your `Procfile`:

  ```
  web: expo start --port $PORT
  ```
- commit, and redeploy.

In general, your `web` process should only tell Heroku the command that needs to run for your server to start. Packing other tasks into it is a code smell.

Comment: Thanks, this gets me a step closer, it manages to bind to the port. However I get a json response when visiting the url of the heroku app, and secondly the app crashes almost immediately because of the file watcher (it doesn't look like there is a way to start expo without watch mode)

Comment: "I get a json response when visiting the url of the heroku app"—what do you expect to get instead? I'm not familiar with Expo. "the app crashes almost immediately because of the file watcher (it doesn't look like there is a way to start expo without watch mode)"
—it doesn't make sense to have a file watcher on Heroku due to its ephemeral filesystem. Heroku isn't a remote workstation. Why do you want this?

Comment: Expo gives you a really easy Dev environment, where localhost provides a qr code that can be scanned with the expo app on a mobile device which spins up a Dev version of the native app. I am trying to get a version of this to live on a heroku that can be accessed by myself and 3 other people. The reason is that it is a lot of friction to set up a staging environment for the ios version, and I thought this would be a quick hacky solution that I could use in the meantime.